# Spreadtab related error, "File ended while scanning use of \ST@get@body"

Tags: errors

## Question

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{spreadtab}


\title{ Dalhousie World Vision Society Budget}
\date{October 14, 2013}
\author{Joseph Harrietha\\ Treasurer, Dalhousie World Vision Society}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l}}

@ Project       &@Item               &@Quantity   &@Expense &@Notes                         &@Total (Tax Included) (\$)   \\ \midrule
@ Awareness     &@                   &@           &@        &@                              &@                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Big Posters        &@20         &@27      &@9\$ per sq ft. 3sq ft.        &\STcopy{v}{!c3*!d3*1.15}     \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Small Posters      &@50         &@1       &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Brochures          &@200        &@1.50    &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Handouts           &@100        &@1       &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Misc Supplies      &@1          &@50      &@                              &                             \\ \midrule
@30 Hour Famine &@People Attending:  &@20         &@        &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Food               &c8          &@20      &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Activities         &@5          &@25      &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Supplies           &@1          &@100     &@                              &                             \\ \midrule
@Water Run      &@People Attending:  &@No Count   &@        &@Assuming same number as 30HF  &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Supplies           &c8          &@10      &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Base Setup         &@1          &@100     &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Shirts             &c8          &@10      &@                              &                             \\ \midrule
@Total          &@                   &@           &         &@                              &@Total Here
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

Most of the errors say: "Misplaced alignment tab character &"

## UPDATE

I removed the @ on all cells containing numbers, and now I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{spreadtab}


\title{ Dalhousie World Vision Society Budget}
\date{October 14, 2013}
\author{Joseph Harrietha\\ Treasurer, Dalhousie World Vision Society}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l}}

@ Project       &@Item               &@Quantity   &@Expense &@Notes                         &@Total (Tax Included) (\$)   \\ \midrule
@ Awareness     &@                   &@           &@        &@                              &@                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Big Posters        &20         &27      &@9\$ per sq ft. 3sq ft.        &\STcopy{v}{!c3*!d3*1.15}     \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Small Posters      &50         &1       &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Brochures          &200        &1.50    &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Handouts           &100        &1       &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Misc Supplies      &1          &50      &@                              &                             \\ \midrule
@30 Hour Famine &@People Attending:  &20         &        &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Food               &c8         &20      &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Activities         &5          &25      &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Supplies           &1          &100     &@                              &                             \\ \midrule
@Water Run      &@People Attending:  &@No Count  &@       &@Assuming same number as 30HF  &                             \\ \cline{2-6
@               &@Supplies           &c8         &10      &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Base Setup         &@1         &@100    &                               &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
@               &@Shirts             &c8         &10      &@                               &                             \\ \midrule
@Total          &@                   &@          &        &@                              & \\
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

That only generates the errors:
"File ended while scanning use of \ST@get@body"

Comment: Ow, I got many errors also and a `log` file with 84mb.

Comment: running `pdflatex` in the terminal I got this error: *A reference to a non-numeric or empty cell is not al
lowed! Cell F3 contains a reference to an empty or text cell: C3*

Comment: f3 would be the "\STcopy{v}{!c3*!d3*1.15}", but even if I remove that I still get all the errors.

Comment: Are you sure that cells containing numbers can have @?

Comment: Great minds think alike, I removed the @ On all cells containing numbers, now all I have is a "File ended while scanning use of \ST@get@body", I'll edit the OP to reflect this.

Comment: I guess that you want `\cite{Budget2013}` instead of `\bibliography{Budget2013}`.

Comment: You have `\midrule`s but aren't loading `booktabs`...

Comment: The Bibliography string was incorrect, I removed it completely and updated the OP.
@cgnieder As for the midrule, I replaced the midrule with \hlines and the error did not disappear. Thank you though, as I did not know about booktabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few syntax errors, like `\cline{2-6`. Furthermore you have to exclude all columns were you don't have a quantity value from calculating. And as already pointed out in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140538/spreadtab-related-error-file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-stgetbody/140543#comment317380_140538) of [@cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder)`booktabs` is missing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l}}
    @ Project       &@Item               &@Quantity   &@Expense &@Notes                         &@Total (Tax Included) (\$)   \\ %\midrule
    @ Awareness     &@                   &@           &@        &@                              &@                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Big Posters        &20         &27      &@9\$ per sq ft. 3sq ft.        &\STcopy{v}{!c3*!d3*1.15}     \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Small Posters      &50         &1       &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Brochures          &200        &1.50    &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Handouts           &100        &1       &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Misc Supplies      &1          &50      &@                              &                             \\ %\midrule
    @30 Hour Famine &@People Attending:  &20         &        &@                              &@                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Food               &c8         &20      &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Activities         &5          &25      &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Supplies           &1          &100     &@                              &                             \\ %\midrule
    @Water Run      &@People Attending:  &@No Count  &@       &@Assuming same number as 30HF  &@                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Supplies           &c8         &10      &@                              &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Base Setup         &1         &100    &                               &                             \\ \cline{2-6}
    @               &@Shirts             &c8         &10      &@                               &                             \\ %\midrule
    @Total          &@                   &@          &        &@                              &@ \\
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```